# Finding the largest number in a column in array

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers

First source file

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    extern int transitTime[];
    int time1;
    int i,j;
    int largest;
    printf("Please enter time leaving school.\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1);
    for(i=0;i<time1;i++)
    {
    largest=0;
    printf("The longest travelling time ");

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
    //printf("%d ",transitTime[i+j*11]);
    if(transitTime[i+j*11]>largest)largest=transitTime[i+j*11];
    }

    printf("is %d\n",largest);
    }
}
```

Second source file

```
int transitTime[] ={
 56,58,57,52,54,53,48,49,51,57,62, //bus 8
 39,43,40,34,37,36,31,32,42,49,59, //bus15
 42,47,43,42,51,49,40,41,48,50,58, //22
 50,55,51,49,52,47,49,48,53,41,55, //23
 };
```

The output after debugging the program is

```
Please enter the time leaving school
5
The longest time is 56
The longest time is 58
The longest time is 57
The longest time is 52
The longest time is 54
```

How do i make the program to select the row which i want for exmple:

```
Please enter the time leaving school
5
The longest time is 54
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do your own homework

Comment: Try to find the largest element in each column and store it in array, then you can query that array using column number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this way

```
void main(void)
{
    extern int transitTime[];
    int time1;
    int i,j;
    int largest;
    printf("Please enter time leaving school.\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1);
//    for(i=0;i<time1;i++)
//    {
    i = time1 - 1;
    largest=0;
    printf("The longest travelling time ");

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
    //printf("%d ",transitTime[i+j*11]);
    if(transitTime[i+j*11]>largest)
                largest=transitTime[i+j*11];
    }

    printf("is %d\n",largest);
 //   }
}
```

No need for loop with i variable.

Just choose value of `i` as `time1 -1`

Comment: @Newprogrammer258 welcome to stackoverflow. Understand some stuff about stackoverflow and how it works and life will be great. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I'm slowly learning programming and i love stockoverflow a lot. Many thanks! :)